# What happens with multiple Blood Moons and Magical Hack?

Tags: magic-the-gathering

There are 2 [Blood Moon](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Blood%20Moon) in play and I cast [Magical Hack](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Magical%20Hack) changing the wording of one of them from mountains to swamps.

What happens to my [Tundra](https://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Card/Details.aspx?name=Tundra)?

Comment: Did you target the Blood Moon which entered play first or second?

Comment: What difference those it make?

Comment: Whether they are mountains or swamps.

Answer (score 4):

**Your non-basic lands will be turned into Mountains or Swamps, depending on which Blood Moon you hacked.**

The Blood Moons generate type-changing effects in layer 4 of the effect layer system.

> 613.1. The values of an object’s characteristics are determined by starting with the actual object. For a card, that means the values of the characteristics printed on that card. For a token or a copy of a spell or card, that means the values of the characteristics defined by the effect that created it. Then all applicable continuous effects are applied in a series of layers in the following order:

> 613.1d Layer 4: Type-changing effects are applied. These include effects that change an object’s card type, subtype, and/or supertype.

Magical Hack happens in layer 3, so it can't interfere with the outcome.

When two effects in the same layer compete to do something, the latest of these effects wins.

> 613.3. Within layers 2–6, apply effects from characteristic-defining abilities first (see rule 604.3), then all other effects in timestamp order (see rule 613.7). Note that dependency may alter the order in which effects are applied within a layer. (See rule 613.8.)

> 613.7. Within a layer or sublayer, determining which order effects are applied in is usually done using a timestamp system. An effect with an earlier timestamp is applied before an effect with a later timestamp.

So if you hacked the first Blood Moon that entered the battlefield, then non-basic lands will be Mountains. If you hacked the second one, Swamps.

Comment: I think it's worth mentioning that the effect from Magical Hack itself is a Layer 3 effect, to confirm that it does affect what happens with Blood Moon's effect.

Comment: My instant analysis was backwards from yours: if you hack the first Blood Moon, that changes all non-basic lands to Swamps. The second Blood Moon then looks at the board and says "I see a bunch of Swamps, nothing for me to do here". What am I missing?

Comment: @PhilipKendall Per the final Gatherer ruling on the card "This effect [...] won't turn any land into a basic land.". Having a basic land type doesn't make a land basic.

Comment: @PhilipKendall it changes them into swamps by adding the type swamp, but it does not add the basic supertype. That means the second blood moon will see a bunch of "land - swamp" as non-basic lands and change them again. The only card that changes non-basic lands into basic lands is [Rootpath Purifier](https://scryfall.com/card/brc/24/rootpath-purifier).

Comment: And Underground Sea is both an island and a swamp, but not a basic land.